# In robot framework I cannot get locators in material-ui calendar

Tags: selenium-webdriver, datepicker, material-ui, robotframework

I need to select the year, month, and day for my test in Robot Framework but they do not have locators. For the calendar in our web app, DevOps used picker ("@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0","@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10").
Can someone share the knowledge on how to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: can you share your url to check and do you want pick date from web page ?

Comment: Adding image of html code is bad practice. no one will write that for you to reproduce the case. Please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly. Currently we dont know what are your trials and error to solve this problem.

Comment: In regards to URL send me an email please and I will send it to you in private: katerinafixter@gmail.com